# How to extract data from nested objects with in an array

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Trying to load some data into a table from an API call; the issue being I cant seem to grab the data from the nested objects within the array.

I've managed to load all of it, minus the splits of survey_data - that all went into one column. Tried using cross apply with openjson but that failed to extract the option and answer.

The end goal is extract and load the id, option, answer [from the Options object] along side the question in the survey data object.

What's a decent method of tackling those nested objects?

Payload example (took some data out for privacy)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "8",
      "contact_id": "12345",
      "status": "Incomplete",
      "is_test_data": "1",
      "data_quality": [
        
      ],
      "region": "111",
      "survey_data": {
        "3": {
          "id": 3,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "I think apples are the best",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10004": {
              "id": 10004,
              "option": "Agree",
              "answer": "Agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "6": {
          "id": 6,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "I think oranges are the best",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10019": {
              "id": 10019,
              "option": "Agree",
              "answer": "Agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "5": {
          "id": 5,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "fruit care about my health",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10014": {
              "id": 10014,
              "option": "Agree",
              "answer": "Agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "7": {
          "id": 7,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "fruit are healthy",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10024": {
              "id": 10024,
              "option": "Agree",
              "answer": "Agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "33": {
          "id": 33,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "fruit help me focus",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10052": {
              "id": 10052,
              "option": "Agree",
              "answer": "Agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "12": {
          "id": 12,
          "type": "ESSAY",
          "question": "i hope to...",
          "section_id": 4,
          "shown": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "contact_id": "67890",
      "status": "Complete",
      "is_test_data": "1",
      "data_quality": [
        
      ],
      "region": "456",
      "survey_data": {
        "3": {
          "id": 3,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "I think Apples are the best.",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10003": {
              "id": 10003,
              "option": "Strongly agree",
              "answer": "Strongly agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "6": {
          "id": 6,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "I think oranges are the best",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10018": {
              "id": 10018,
              "option": "Strongly agree",
              "answer": "Strongly agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "5": {
          "id": 5,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "fruit care about my health",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10013": {
              "id": 10013,
              "option": "Strongly agree",
              "answer": "Strongly agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "7": {
          "id": 7,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "fruit are healthy",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10023": {
              "id": 10023,
              "option": "Strongly agree",
              "answer": "Strongly agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "33": {
          "id": 33,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "fruit help me focus",
          "section_id": 4,
          "options": {
            "10053": {
              "id": 10053,
              "option": "Strongly agree",
              "answer": "Strongly agree"
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "12": {
          "id": 12,
          "type": "ESSAY",
          "question": "I hope to...",
          "section_id": 4,
          "answer": "eat all the fruit",
          "shown": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say it but with the dynamic object names comes the need to use something that works dynamically.

My suggestion would be to use the `Advanced Data Operations` connector and more specifically the `Json to Table` operation ...

[image: Json to Table]

Basically, the `JSON` variable holds the JSON you provided in your question.

I've used the `Filter` option to only give me records where the `answer` property is not equal to null.

***Note:** Something looks off with the last item in your json so just check that.  It may have skewed the results.*

That produced the resulting output which looks like this ...

```
[
  {
    "status": "Incomplete",
    "region": "111",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10004,
    "contact_id": "12345",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "I think apples are the best",
    "option": "Agree",
    "answer": "Agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Incomplete",
    "region": "111",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10014,
    "contact_id": "12345",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "fruit care about my health",
    "option": "Agree",
    "answer": "Agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Incomplete",
    "region": "111",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10019,
    "contact_id": "12345",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "I think oranges are the best",
    "option": "Agree",
    "answer": "Agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Incomplete",
    "region": "111",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10024,
    "contact_id": "12345",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "fruit are healthy",
    "option": "Agree",
    "answer": "Agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Incomplete",
    "region": "111",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10052,
    "contact_id": "12345",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "fruit help me focus",
    "option": "Agree",
    "answer": "Agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Complete",
    "region": "456",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10003,
    "contact_id": "67890",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "I think Apples are the best.",
    "option": "Strongly agree",
    "answer": "Strongly agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Complete",
    "region": "456",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10013,
    "contact_id": "67890",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "fruit care about my health",
    "option": "Strongly agree",
    "answer": "Strongly agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Complete",
    "region": "456",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10018,
    "contact_id": "67890",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "I think oranges are the best",
    "option": "Strongly agree",
    "answer": "Strongly agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Complete",
    "region": "456",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10023,
    "contact_id": "67890",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "fruit are healthy",
    "option": "Strongly agree",
    "answer": "Strongly agree"
  },
  {
    "status": "Complete",
    "region": "456",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 12,
    "contact_id": "67890",
    "type": "ESSAY",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "I hope to...",
    "option": null,
    "answer": "eat all the fruit"
  },
  {
    "status": "Complete",
    "region": "456",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "id": 10053,
    "contact_id": "67890",
    "type": "parent",
    "shown": true,
    "section_id": 4,
    "question": "fruit help me focus",
    "option": "Strongly agree",
    "answer": "Strongly agree"
  }
]
```

Now, I'm not 100% sure if that will fit the bill for you perfectly because there are a number of properties that are not represented because of the fact that the property is represented multiple times but if you're only after the `id`, `option` and `answer` properties then you can see them there.

Obviously, this is a paid connector but it's hell cheap and does what you need.